# MySql script to convert all DB datetime fields value from a specific timezone to UTC

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

We have a DB schema that incorporates many datetime fields in many tables, with their data stored in local timezone.
Now all these values need to be converted to UTC.

I try to make a script which will find and update all these values.

Something like an automated update command.

Is there any quick and safe way?

What I found so far:

1) A way to get all such fields from my db

```
SELECT table_name, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE  
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_schema = 'my_db' AND COLUMN_TYPE='datetime';
```

2) A way to update all the data

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = CONVERT_TZ( my_column, 'EST', 'UTC' );
```

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT_TZ is the fastest and easiest way to convert between timezones AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... yet, what I need is a do-it-all script! one that would get the tables to be converted, get the current timezone, generate the update commands and run them... I know I maybe ask for too much... :-/

Answer (score 0):

The way I finally worked-around it was to create a command that *generates* all the update commands with string concatenation...

This is what I initially executed on information_schema:

```
SELECT concat('UPDATE ', table_schema,'.',table_name,' SET ',column_name,' = CONVERT_TZ( ',column_name,',\'+03:00\',\'+00:00\' );')   
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
Where table_schema = 'mydb' AND COLUMN_TYPE='datetime';
```

This gave me a set of commands like:

```
UPDATE mydb.table1 SET OccuredOn = CONVERT_TZ( OccuredOn,'+03:00','+00:00' );
UPDATE mydb.table1 SET CreatedOn = CONVERT_TZ( CreatedOn,'+03:00','+00:00' );
UPDATE mydb.table2 SET LastUpdatedOn = CONVERT_TZ( LastUpdatedOn,'+03:00','+00:00' );
```

(... and many more)

... which were ready to execute and have the desired result in around 5 sec.

Obviously this is not the optimized way to do it, but I had the freedom to do it as the db is yet short in data (some tens of thousands records in around 30 tables).

Needless to say you have to use with caution in large DBs (execution time may be long etc)